# Retrieve n items from each group in linq

Tags: c#, linq, greatest-n-per-group

I search more on this site for "get 4 top item from each group", but there are many topic about get first item from each group like this

```
var rr = db.Products
           .GroupBy(x => x.ProductSubTypeCategoryId, (key, g) => g.OrderBy(e => e.PersianName)
           .Take(4).ToList());
```

or

```
var rr = db.Products
           .GroupBy(x => x.ProductSubTypeCategoryId).Select(g => new { pname = g.Key, count = g.Count() });
```

but return only first item from each group. How can I change the code to get 4 items from each group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rr = db.Products.GroupBy(x => x.ProductSubTypeCategoryId).Select(g => new { GroupName = g.Key, Items = g.Take(4).ToList() });
```

This should give you an anonymous object with a `GroupName` property that returns the ProductSubTypeCategoryId and an `Items` property that returns a list of up to 4 items for each group.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this with `SelectMany()`

```
var rr = db.Products
       .GroupBy(x => x.ProductSubTypeCategoryId)
       .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(e => e.PersianName).Take(4))
       .ToList();
```